# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\INFORMATICA\CRUD\buscar_usuario.php on line 74

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo un buscador dentro de mi CRUD de tareas. hice este php con el nombre buscar_usuario.php para que cuando en el index.php presionaran el botón de buscar apareciera este código, el de "buscar_usuario.php". El error es el del título: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\INFORMATICA\CRUD\buscar_usuario.php on line 74. 
Quiero saber como resolver este error para que cuando busque una palabra me salgan las que coinciden en mi base de datos con esa palabra, ya sea por título, por descripción, fecha en que fué creado o estado.
Esta es la captura de el "buscar_usuario.php"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Como ven en el "index.php"si tengo tareas agregadas, pero ya cuando doy buscar ya me aparece el error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```php
<?php include("db.php"); ?>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<body>
<main class="container p-1">
  <?php 
    $busqueda= strtolower($_REQUEST['busqueda']);
    if(empty($busqueda)){
      header("location:index.php");
    }

  ?>
  <main class="container p-4">
    <form action="buscar_usuario.php" method="get" class="form_search">
      <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar" value="<?php echo $busqueda; ?>">
      <input type="submit" name="s" value="Buscar" class="btn_search">
    </form>
  </main>
  <main class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- MESSAGES -->

      <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) { ?>
      <div class="alert alert-<?= $_SESSION['message_type']?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <?= $_SESSION['message']?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <?php session_unset(); } ?>

      <!-- ADD TASK FORM -->
      <div class="card card-body">
        <form action="save_task.php" method="POST">
          <h4>Crear nueva tarea:</h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Título de la tarea" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="description" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción de la tarea" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Estado:
              <select name="estado">
                <option>Pendiente</option>
                <option>Realizada</option>
              </select></p>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="save_task"value="Guardar tarea" class="guardar">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Creado el día: </th>
            <th>Acción</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <?php
          $result_tasks = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT u.title, u.description, u.created_at, u.estado FROM task 
                                                            WHERE(  u.title LIKE '$busqueda' OR
                                                                    u.description LIKE '$busqueda' OR
                                                                    u.created_at LIKE '$busqueda' OR
                                                                    u.estado LIKE '$busqueda')
                                                                    AND estatus=1
                                                                    ");
          $result=mysqli_num_rows($result_tasks);
          if($result>0){

          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_tasks)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['created_at']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <i class="fas fa-marker"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="delete_task.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php }} ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Obtienes este mensaje cuando hay error al ejecutar mysqli_query(). Revisa la consulta, cópiala y trata de ejecutarla en PhpMyAdmin, seguramente encontrarás el problema.